# How to search within list of integer ranges efficiently - java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, range

**How to search within list of integer ranges efficiently?**

I have list of ranges with some duplicate values. I want to get *value*, if input number is within range.

e.g.

| Range Start | Range End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 75 | A |
| 95 | 200 | A |
| 300 | 455 | B |
| 570 | 650 | C |
| 201 | 250 | A |
| 255 | 275 | B |

***Note**: Start and end ranges are not overlapped.*

- Input     260 Expected output     B
- Input     195 Expected output     A

Currently, I am saving in HashMap <String, String> and Storing  *{“10-75” , A} {’95-200”, B}*…
I am

- looping through all keys of Map,
- split each key,
- convert to int and
- check given number is within range or not.
- if yes get value for that key

I am thinking there may be some more efficient way to handle this in Java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into using a tree structure here.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, even just six `if`s checking whether a number is in a certain range would be more efficient than using a map. Maybe not elegant, but efficient for sure.

Comment: I would have used `if`'s if the range list was small. My list is in hundreds .:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)'s `RangeMap`:

```
RangeMap<Integer, Character> rangeMap = TreeRangeMap.create();
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(10, 75), 'A');
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(95, 200), 'A');
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(300, 455), 'B');
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(570, 650), 'C');
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(201, 250), 'A');
rangeMap.put(Range.closed(255, 275), 'B');

Character character = rangeMap.get(61);
Character character2 = rangeMap.get(244);
Character character3 = rangeMap.get(270);

System.out.println(character);
System.out.println(character2);
System.out.println(character3);
```

Output:

```
A
A
B
```

Note: for some reason, it's marked with `@Beta` https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3376 so I would want to make sure it's OK if it's for production use.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Comment: For something so relatively simple to do in Java I question using a 3rd party library just to get  this capability (unless of course the OP is already using Guava).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using a `TreeMap` and `Entry` like this using regular Java.
If no range exists for the supplied argument it returns `Not Found`

Here is the map for containing the ranges.

- it is a TreeMap
- the key is the lower part of a range.
- the value is a `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` with the upper part of the range and the String.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,String>> nmap =
        new TreeMap<>();
```

The method for constructing the map.

```
public static void build(
        NavigableMap<Integer, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String>> map,
                                         int start, int end, String v) {
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String> e = new 
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,String>(end,v);
        map.put(start, e);
}
```

A lambda for retrieving the String.

```
Function<Integer,String> get = k->{
        Entry<Integer, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer,String>> entry = 
                             nmap.floorEntry(k);
        if (entry == null) {
                  return "Not Found";
        }
        if (k > entry.getValue().getKey()) {
                  return "Not Found";
        }
        return entry.getValue().getValue();        
};
```

Building the map for each range

```
build(nmap, 10, 75, "A");
build(nmap, 95, 200, "A");
build(nmap, 300, 455, "B");
build(nmap, 570, 650, "C");
build(nmap, 201, 250, "A");
build(nmap, 255, 275, "B");
```

Testing

```
int[] testData = { 9, 23, 255, 99, 94, 201 };
for (int i : testData) {
    System.out.printf("%4d -> %s%n",i, get.apply(i));
}
```

Prints

```
   9 -> Not Found
  23 -> A
 255 -> B
  99 -> A
  94 -> Not Found
 201 -> A
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try three if-else statements?

**Assumptions: Start and End values of ranges are considered as values within the given range.**

'D' denotes that the given value belongs to neither of the defined range values.

Sample code:

```
 public static char findRangeValue(int number){

        if((number >= 10 && number <=75) ||(number >= 95 && number <=250) ){
            return 'A';
        }else if((number >= 255 && number <=275) ||(number >= 300 && number <=455)  ){
            return 'B';
        }else if(number >= 570 && number <=650 ){
            return 'C';
        }
           return 'D';
    }
```

Sample method call and outputs :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(findRangeValue(265));
        System.out.println(findRangeValue(11));
        System.out.println(findRangeValue(575));
    }
```

Outputs:

```
B
A
C
```

Comment: Thank you. My actual range list is in hundreds. this may not be elegant solution for my case/